# Mixing c++ and assembly cant pass multiple paramaters from C++ function to assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, masm

I've been frustrated by passing parameters from a c++ function to assembly. I couldn't find anything that helped on Google and would really like your help. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and masm to compile my assembly code.

This is a simplified version of my c++ file where I call the assembly procedure `set_clock`

```
int main()
{
    TimeInfo localTime;
    char clock[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };
    set_clock(clock,&localTime); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I run into problems in the assembly file. I can't figure out why the second parameter passed to the function turns out huge. I was going off my textbook, which shows similar code with PROC followed by parameters. I don't know why the first parameter is passed successfully and the second one isn't. Can someone tell me the correct way to pass multiple parameters?

```
.code
set_clock PROC, 
    array:qword,address:qword
    mov rdx,array   ; works fine memory address: 0x1052440000616
    mov rdi,address ; value of rdi is 14757395258967641292
    mov al, [rdx] 
    mov [rdi],al    ; ERROR: cant access that memory location
    ret
set_clock ENDP
END
```

Comment: `prog.cpp:3:5: error: ‘TimeInfo’ was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MASM's high-level crap is biting you in the ass.  **x64 Windows passes the first 4 args in `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, `r9`** (for any of those 4 that are integer/pointer).

```
mov rdx,array
mov rdi,address
```

assembles to

```
mov  rdx, rcx    ; clobber 2nd arg with a copy of the 1st
mov  rdi, rdx    ; copy array again
```

Use a disassembler to check for yourself.  Always a good idea to check the real machine code by disassembling or using your debuggers disassembly instead of source mode, if anything weird is happening with assembler macros.

---

**I'm not sure why this would result in an inaccessible memory location**.  If both args really are pointers to locals, then it should just be loading and storing back into the same stack location.  But if `char clock[4]` is a `const` in static storage, it might be in a read-only memory page which would explain the store failing.

Either way, use a debugger and find out.

---

BTW, `rdi` is a call-preserved (aka non-volatile) register in the x64 Windows convention. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx).  Use call-clobbered registers for scratch regs unless you run out and need to save/restore some call-preserved regs.  See also Agner Fog's calling conventions doc (http://agner.org/optimize/), and other links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

It's call-clobbered in x86-64 System V, which also passes args in different registers.  Maybe you were looking at a different example?

---

Hopefully-fixed version, using `movzx` to avoid a false dependency on RAX when loading a byte.

```
set_clock PROC, 
    array:qword,address:qword
    movzx    eax, byte ptr [array] 
    mov      [address], al
    ret
set_clock ENDP
```

I don't use MASM, but I think `array:qword` makes `array` an alias for `rcx`.  Or you could skip declaring the parameters and just use `rcx` and `rdx` directly, and document it with comments.  That would be easier for everyone to understand.

You definitely don't want useless `mov reg,reg` instructions cluttering your code; if you're writing in asm in the first place, wasted instructions would cut into any speedups you're getting.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will access `rcx` and `rdx` and annotate like you suggested to make things easier for everyone. Your right, the `char clock[4]` was declared `const`

Comment: In such situations (different assembler -- Delphi builtin --, but same problem) I don't use the parameter names but always `RCX` and `RDX`, etc. directly. That way, it is always clear which register contains what.